# Prove that $x^{n-1}=x^{-1}$ (Groups)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, inverse

Suppose $G$ is a group, $x\in G$ and  order$(x)=n$.
I have to show that $x^{-1}=x^{n-1}$

Is it sufficient to just say $x^{n-1}=x^nx^{-1}=1_Gx^{-1}=x^{-1}$?

This is a homework question and I'm not sure whether it needs to be done without assuming you can use index laws with regards to elements of a group.

Any other ways or is this okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that would be correct, assuming that you can use the fact that$$(\forall m,m\in\mathbb Z):x^{m+n}=x^mx^n.$$Or you can say that$$1_G=x^n=x^{n-1}.x$$and that therefore $x^{n-1}=x^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof correct and nice.

A slightly different proof goes as follows:
$$
x x^{n-1}=x^n=1_G
\implies
x^{n-1}=x^{-1}
$$
either by multiplying on the left by $x^{-1}$ or by using the uniqueness of inverses.